# HTML output in PHP code

Tags: php, html

I am customizing part of a PHP script that outputs HTML based on a previously defined variable ($title), but I'm having some trouble.

This is the code:

```
$out .= html( "div id='term-list-$taxonomy'", $title .html( "ul id='filter-list' class='term-list'", $list ));
```

It currently creates this html:

```
<div id="term-list-taxonomy>
Title
<ul id="filter-list" class="term-list">
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
...
```

I'm trying to make it output this (make the title a link):

```
<div id="term-list-taxonomy>
<a id="filter-title" href="#">
Title
</a>
<ul id="filter-list" class="term-list">
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Showing what this `html()` function does would be helpful... Also note that the html is broken. There's no closing `"` inside the first div's `id`.

Comment: Ask us a question when you need any help! If you don't know how to warp the title in <a>, we need more information, like the html() function and maybe where you are getting $title from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what little you've given us about how `html()` works, I would speculate that you'd want replace:

```
$title
```

with:

```
html("a id='filter-title' href='#'", $title)
```

yielding:

```
$out .= html( "div id='term-list-$taxonomy'", html("a id='filter-title' href='#'", $title) . html( "ul id='filter-list' class='term-list'", $list ));
```